# Xbox 360 Controller Drivers not Installing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, xbox360

Following these [instructions from Microsoft](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/xbox-controller-for-windows-setup#117609985a39498daf56ee37ff7bbd90) my aftermarket Xbox 360 controller is not working on Windows 7.  Any suggestions?

[image: Missing Driver Alert]

Comment: Is it possible that the root cause of the problem is that you are using an *aftermarket* Xbox 360 controller?  Have you tested the procedure utilizing a genuine Microsoft Xbox 360 controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often use the available drivers after telling Windows which drivers to use:

1. Download and install [the driver software](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/xbox-controller-for-windows-setup) for your windows version
2. Plug in the Xbox 360 Controller
3. Open the Device Manager (<kbd>[image: WindowsKey]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type `devmgmt.msc`)
4. Find the icon for the controller, likely under other devices

[image: Image of Icon Showing Missing Driver]

5. Double-click the controller icon and select the driver tab
6. Select the "Update Driver" button
7. Select "Browse my computer"
8. Select "Let me pick from a list"
9. Select "Microsoft Common Controller For Windows Class" on Windows 7, or "Xbox 360 Peripherals" on Windows 8+, and press next
10. Select the appropriate driver and press next

[image: Image of pick driver version]

11. Select 'Yes' you really do want to use this driver

([Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/xbox-360-wired-controller-does-not-install-windows/0cafc5a3-665d-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5))